# String to number java

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Just looking for a little bit of help... Why is my output on giving "due". When it should output all the numbers such as uno, due, tres, quattro and clinque all in a list.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
package numbersAndStrings;

public class ItalianNumberToStringConverter {

public static void main1(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
 public enum NumberInWords{
       uno,due,tres,quattro,clinque
}

public static NumberInWords numberM(int i) {
    return NumberInWords.values()[i-1];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 2;
        System.out.println(numberM(num));
}

public static String convertNumberToString(Integer 
i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] ItNums = {
            "",
            "uno",
            "due",
            "tres",
            "quattro",
            "clinque"
    };
    String myString = "";
    myString = ItNums[i];

    if(i == 1)
        myString = ItNums[1];
    else if(i == 2)
        myString = ItNums[2];
    else if (i == 3)
        myString = ItNums[3];
    else if (i == 4)
        myString = ItNums[4];
    else if (i == 5)
        myString = ItNums[5];

    System.out.println(myString);
    return myString;

    }
```

Comment: You are never calling `convertNumberToString`.

Comment: Furthermore, your if-else ladder is completely redundant. `myString = ItNums[i];` is enough.

Comment: are you trying to iterate through the list?

Comment: @NilsKähler Yes through the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate through the list and print every element in the list you can do this, use a `forEach` loop to iterate over the list and print it out into the console.

```
public class ItalianNumberToStringConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertNumberToString(3));
    }

    public static String convertNumberToString(Integer i) {
        String[] ItNums = {
                "",
                "uno",
                "due",
                "tres",
                "quattro",
                "clinque"
        };

        String myString = ItNums[i];

        for (String num : ItNums) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }

        return myString;
    }
}
```

You need to call `convertNumberToString()` method in your main method to run it. This will print every element in the console, and return the string for the number and then print that in the main method, in this case if you call, `convertNumberToString(3)` it will print "tres" so you will see the list being printed followed by "tres".